# Only 1 out of 2 nvme same capacity ssds is detected on CentOS kernel 4.20 ml version

Tags: centos, kernel, ssd, nvme

I have plugged 2 nvme pcie ssd of same capacity on to my dell server running CentOS 7.6 and kernel version 4.20-ml but only one gets detected all the time.

While booting from kernel 4.20, an error: "nvme nvme2: ignoring ctrl due to duplicate subnqn" is displayed but that's not the case with kernel version 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bug in Kernel / NVMe firmware:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1803692

Try to update the firmware of your SSD / NVMe first. Here a quick howto for those who has this issue with Intel drives:

Firmware update with Intel SSD Data Center Tool (DCT)
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=SSD+Firmware+Update+Tool

```
# Download and install DCT
wget https://downloadmirror.intel.com/28999/eng/Intel_SSD_Data_Center_Tool_3.0.20_Linux.zip -O /tmp/Intel_SSD_Data_Center_Tool_3.0.20_Linux.zip
unzip -d /tmp /tmp/Intel_SSD_Data_Center_Tool_3.0.20_Linux.zip
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/isdct_3.0.20-1_amd64.deb

# show drive data
isdct show -intelssd

# update 1st drive
isdct load -intelssd 0

reboot

# update second drive
isdct load -intelssd 1
```